# Why can't I use $location.path() to get data with $resource?

Tags: angularjs

I've written a service to get data using $resource from a database:

```
    .factory('Students', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/students', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
    }])
```

but I want to fetch different data when the url of my page changes. So I changed it to this:

```
    factory('Students', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var urlBase = '/group-';
    return function(urlExt) {
        var url = urlBase + urlExt;
        return $resource(url, {}, {
            query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
        });
    }
}]);
```

And I call it in my controller like this:

```
    $scope.students = Students($location.path());
```

I don't get an error, but it doesn't return anything. Does it have to do with the fact that the page isn't refreshing but loading template views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do it like this:

```
.factory('Students', ['$resource', '$location', function($resource, $location) {
  return $resource($location.path(), {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
  });
}])
```

You could also try:

```
.factory('Students', ['$resource', '$location', function ($resource, $location) {
  return $resource(':dest', {dest:$location.path()});
}]);
```

I'm not sure if `:dest` will work without a leading slash, and I'm pretty sure `$location.path()` has a leading slash, so you may need to change it to:

```
.factory('Students', ['$resource', '$location', function ($resource, $location) {
  return $resource('/:dest', {dest:$location.path().substr(1)});
}]);
```

Ok, per your comment, to prevent url encoding error, try the first one again, but inject $sce and use it to whitelist the url, which may have been the original issue with that one:

```
.factory('Students', ['$resource', '$location', '$sce', function($resource, $location, $sce) {
  return $resource($sce.trustAsResourceUrl($location.path()), {}, {
    query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true}
  });
}])
```

Comment: When I add $location as a dependency it gives me a "bad configuration" error.

Comment: does the error occur just from adding $location as a dependency, or when you set the url to $location.path()?

Comment: It looks like just setting the url to $location.path() might be the issue there. Just loading it as a dependency doesn't give me an error.

Comment: I like that solution, but now it's saying that $location is not defined. Do I need to configure $location before it's used in a factory?

Comment: `.factory('Students', ['$resource', '$location', function ($resource, $location)` If you are injecting it into your factory it should be defined

Comment: Ha, that was an embarrassing mistake. But that solved that error. I don't know if I should start another question for this, but now the $location.path()/$location.url() returned is giving me a %2F instead of /, and that's the last thing I think I need to solve to get this working. Any suggestions?